# Match background with users current weather conditions

Tags: reactjs, background-image, openweathermap, weather-api

I am new to React, trying to learn and I have this unsolvable problem. I have developed a weather app, I'm still working on it, but at this moment I am stuck for 3 days trying to have a background image that changes depending on the users weather conditions. I have tried something using the icon, from openweather API. I used the same method to get the icon (image from my folder) to match users weather conditions.

```
   import React from "react";
   export default function Background(props) {
const codeMapping = {
"01d": "clear-sky-day",
"01n": "clear-sky-night",
"02d": "cloudy-day",
"02n": "cloudy-night",
"03d": "cloudy-day",
"03n": "cloudy-night",
"04d": "cloudy-day",
"04n": "cloudy-night",
"09d": "shower-rain-day",
"09n": "shower-rain-night",
"10d": "rain-day",
"10n": "rain-night",
"11d": "thunderstorm-day",
"11n": "thunderstorm-night",
"13d": "snow-day",
"13n": "snow-night",
"50d": "fog-day",
"50n": "fog-night",
};
let name = codeMapping[props.code];
return (
<img
  className="background"
  src={`background/${name}.jpg`}
  alt={props.alt}
  size="cover"
/>
);
}
```

So... in order to get "icon" of the input city by the user I have to call `"<Background cod={weatherData.icon} alt={weatherData.description} />"` from the function "Search" which is the function handling the submit form and running api call for input city. But the image is not showing(img[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRTBu.png)), but to have the img as a background I would call `<Background>` from my App function(img[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKNTQ.png)), but in this case I will not have access to the real icon value from the input city. I should mention I have a folder in "src" called background and the images names match the codes name from the mapping.
Thank you in advance!

[current preview of my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRTBu.png)
[how I see in other documentation I should set a background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKNTQ.png)

Comment: In your `App` function, you are setting `<div style={ backgroundImage: <Background />}>` You cannot set an HTML element `img` as a css property.

Comment: As far as i can tell from your code, you try to inject an html img element in the style property of  your App div. This cannot work. You should either put the background in as is in your render method, or change the Background function to not be a react component and return just the url string, e.g. `return("url(background/"+name+".jpg)");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the `code` from `Search.js` as the state.

##### `App.js`

```js
const codeMapping = {
    "01d": "clear-sky-day",
    "01n": "clear-sky-night",
};

export const App = () => {

    const [code, setCode] = useState(null) // <-- We'll update this from Search.js
    const [backgroundImage, setBackgroundImage] = useState("")

    useEffect(() => {
        // Set background value based on the code
        setBackgroundImage(codeMapping[`${code}`]) 
    }, [code]); // <-- useEffect will run everytime the code changes

    return (
        <div style={{
            height: '100px', 
            width: '100px',
            backgroundImage: `${backgroundImage || "defaultBackgroundImage"}`
        }}>
          <Search setCode={setCode} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

##### `Search.js`

```js
import { WeatherContext } from './App';

export const Search = ({ setCode }) => {
  
  const handleClick = (apiResponse) => {
    // Some API call returning the actual code value here //
    setCode(apiResponse)
  }
  
  return (
    <input
      onClick={() => handleClick("01n")}
      type="button"
      value="Change city"
    />
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you all for your answers and @Monstar this is was I was looking for. Before you answering I managed to do it somehow but not by using React on it's true potential so thank you!